# How to remove the Archive button in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

The problem is in new Gmail GUI, the Archive button float on the mail title so it's very easy to wrong click it, and if I don't notice to click `undo`, I will waste my time to search how to unarchive my mail, **everytime** I do it because I can't remember how to unarchive my mail.

So how to get rid of this archive button?

And another question, what is this archive for?

I'm using newest Gmail version/ GUI in Windows 10, browser Chrome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm a little confused on which UI you are using - is this on a mobile browser? Via the app?

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter I'm using Windows 10, not gmail app or in mobile browser. Although using mouse, I sometime click to the `Archieve` button, and don't notice to click `Undo` then I "lost" that email.

Comment: To remove ARCHIVE button:  1) Install Chrome extension "Stylebot".  2) add the following to always run in Gmail: li[data-tooltip="Archive"] {
  display:none;
}.  Similarly, to remove the SNOOZE button, add this: li[data-tooltip="Snooze"] {
  display:none;
}

Answer (score 15):

You can't remove just the archive button (sadly) but you can remove all 3 of the hover buttons via the settings menu

Go `Cog=>Settings=>General`

Then in the "Hover Actions" section and choose "Disable Hover Actions"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and answer the components of your overall question, but there is no easy way to remove the Archive button, here are some suggestions though on how to work around it.

1. How can you get rid of the Archive button: there is no easy way to do this using any of Gmail's native settings. Also, I would argue that removing the Archive button would just leave the Delete button exposed, which is no better than the current situation.
2. Gmail's Archive feature allows you to get email out of your inbox without deleting it. In order to see the email you've archived, just click "All Mail" in the left-side menu.
   [image]

More about Gmail's Archive feature [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Answer (score -3):

As an alternartive you could switch to Google Inbox. It is the new Google email application and it is suppose to replace Gmail any time soon.

Comment: Bummer - Google Inbox will be closed in March 2019: https://www.theverge.com/2018/9/12/17848500/google-inbox-shut-down-sunset-snooze-email-march-2019